# skip last child of router in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following code and I need to skip the last path: 3

```
  path: "/onboarding",
  name: "Onboarding",
  component: Onboarding,
  meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  children: [
    { path: '1', name: "onboarding/1", component:..  },
    { path: '2', name: "onboarding/2", component:.. },
    { path: '3', name: "onboarding/3", component:.. } 
   ]
```

I tried to use the following with no success

```
     if (
     to.name === "onboarding/3" && noCC) {
     next({ path: "/dashboard" });
   }
```

Comment: what does `noCC` represent?

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` condition you should use double `&` to compare the values :

```js
if (to.name === "onboarding/3" && noCC) {
     next({ path: "/dashboard" });
   }
```